# How do I construct a function with these properties?

Tags: probability, functions

I want to construct a function that have these properties:

```
f( x, y) =  f(y,x)
f(-x,-y) = -f(x,y)

f( 1,x) =  1 (if 1≥x>-1)
f(-1,x) = -1 (if 1>x≥-1)
f(1,-1) should be undefined
f(x,-x) = 0

f(x,a) should be growing for all -1 < x < 1
```

And as suspected x, y should be in [-1,1].

I want to use it to create some sort of mean-like value, to use when I have two probabilities (ranging from certainly true (1) to unknown (0) to certainly false (-1)).

How do I construct this function?

Comment: What's $f'(x,a)$?

Comment: what do you mean by $f(1,-1)$ should be undefined, when you next demand that (presumably) for all $x,~f(x,-x)=0$?

Comment: @jokiri, the derivative. I've rewritten that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some geometric considerations, I came up with:

$f(x,y) = (x+y)/(2-|x-y|)$

To construct this function, consider the square in the plane bounded by $-1 \leq x \leq1$ and $-1 \leq y \leq1$.  Now given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the interior of the square, calculate a "signed distance" from the point to the line $y=-x$, which will be $(x_0+y_0)/\sqrt2$.  Now we need to scale the distance in order that we get the appropriate value of $+1$ or $-1$ when the point is on the boundary of the square.  This function gives all the symmetry properties you are looking for, and also gives the correct values on the boundary.

Comment: Nice. But $f(1,x)=1$ is only satisfied for $x\le1$, and $f(-1,x)=-1$ is only satisfied for $x\ge-1$. (It may well be that that's enough, since the text seems to imply a restriction to $x\in[-1,1]$; but then it's weird that the formula specifies the one bound but not the other.)

Comment: @joriki - He's talking about probability space, so we can assume everything is in the square.  I motivated by answer by giving some additional details above.

Comment: That formula works wonderfully! Thank you!